# Error installing mercurial eclipse plugin on 18.04 on Eclipse Photon

Tags: 18.04, eclipse, mercurial

I get this error when trying to install a plugin using the mercurial eclipse drag and drop from the market place.

[image]

The install site is here:
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/mercurialeclipse

From my eclipse Help menu I am able to select "Eclipse Marketplace..." and I get this screen:

[image]

I'm on ubuntu 18.04 and eclipse is version 4.8.0

Comment: Do you have the eclipse marketplace client installed?

Comment: @RayAntebioni Is there a way to check? I've updated the description with the Marketplace dialog that appears in the description. In the past with Mars and Luna I've never had to explicitly install the market place client so assumed that with Photon that would be the same.

Comment: Check this out https://www.eclipse.org/mpc/

Comment: Whoops, just realized you have it installed already, please disregard that..